# microphone not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

`pavucontrol` input devices: Microphone (Unplugged). Unmuted

I dont know if it is supposed to show the availability of device as (Unplugged), but i do have an internal mic available in my system (Thinkpad X1 carbon 7th gen). I cannot see any device listed under Settings>Soundound>Input

Tried the basic solutions like resetting the pavucontrol profile and then restarting the machine. They do not work

How do i get the inbuilt audio to work

Comment: This seems to be a general problem with this computer. People have reported it working with some newer drivers and the 5.5 kernel, see eg: https://gist.github.com/hamidzr/dd81e429dc86f4327ded7a2030e7d7d9 which is about doing it for Arch. I haven't seen a fix for the 18.04 stock kernel. I got an external USB mic for mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a dell vostro 7590 9th gen. The current kernel modifications are quite annoying and mess many people drivers.

Comment: i hope 20.04 release doesnt have this problem